# Is there any other difference between the cakes and the cup cakes besides the size?

Tags: cupcakes, cakes

I don't have the small cups, so I place the cup cake batter in big vessels, and I think I have prepared cakes.

Now, I'll get the small cups and place the same batter in the cups, and call them cup cakes.

Does this make sense? Or I am missing a point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct: Cupcakes are just regular sponge cakes cooked in approximately cup-sized tins.

Comment: And typically decorated differently - the icing to cake ratio is about 1:1 for cupcakes I see on TV

Comment: @KateGregory: So similar to a traditional wedding cake ratio? :)

Comment: @KateGregory - I would argue that 1:1 is way overboard on cake:icing ratio. It is more like 4:1 even if you are going overboard on the icing. I frost at about 6:1, and "cupcake bakeries" around here usually are in the neighborhood of 3:1.

Comment: I haven't bought one of these, but when I watch, say, cupcake wars, the height of the icing matches the height of the cake below it, and then they stick candies or chocolate shapes or whatever into that. Seems over the top to me.